# Is this possible to display chrome devtools data inside a web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I wanted to know if it is possible to display the data present in the chrome devtools inside the client web page using javascript ?

For example, if I open the devtool right now, How can I display the network usage or the number of source files chrome actually load, and display that information in a web page ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't, as I know, there are some APIs for extending DevTools, but unfortunately you couldn't access them from javascript.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/devtools/